# How would I go about using the z-index to place my logo above the navigation bar and header?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have split my navigation bar and header into two separate react components. Although, my Logo lies in the navigation bar and I am trying to make it overlap the header component.

This is how it looks on my website
[The logo is the circle on the top left and the header is the cream white colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4JKv.png)

This is how my code looks:

This is my Header HTML (I named it main-container-three)

```
 <div className="main-container-three">
        <div className="admin-container">
        <p className="admin-heading">The Oilixate Shop: Oil Spells</p>
        </div>
```

This is my Header CSS

```
.main-container-three{
  position: relative;
  width: 1440px;
  height: 770px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 78px;
  background: #ECE8DF;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 37px 37px;
}
```

This is my Navigation Bar HTML

```
    <div className="nav-bar">
        <div className="nav-logo"></div>
        <a href="/"><p className="nav-home">Home</p></a>
        <a href="/IndiProduct"><p className="nav-product">Products</p></a>
        <a href="/Checkout"><p className="nav-checkout">Checkout</p></a>
        <a href="/Admin"><p className="nav-admin">Admin</p></a>
        <input type={"text"} placeholder={'Search'} className="search-box"></input>
        <button className="search-btn"></button>
        <div className="shopping-cart">
            {/* <div className="modal"></div> */}
        </div>
        <div className="numb-items">
            <p className="one-item">1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now this is my Navigation Bar CSS

```
.nav-bar{
  width: 100%;
  height: 82px;
  background: #2B4447;
  float: left;
}

.nav-logo{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-left: 31px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.nav-home{
  font-family: 'Inter';
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 324px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #DAEFDE;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.nav-home:hover{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-product{
  font-family: 'Inter';
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 71px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #DAEFDE;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.nav-product:hover{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-checkout{
  font-family: 'Inter';
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 71px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #DAEFDE;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.nav-checkout:hover{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-admin{
  font-family: 'Inter';
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 71px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #DAEFDE;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.nav-admin:hover{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.search-box{
  width: 225px;
  height: 43px;
  margin-top: 29px;
  margin-left: 91px;
  padding-left: 1%;
  background: #ECE8DF;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  float: left;
}

::placeholder{
  color: #000000;
}

.search-btn{
  border-style: none;
  width: 36px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-left: -41px;
  background: #EBA182;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: url("../src/assets/Search.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 21px 21px;
  float: left;
}

.shopping-cart{
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-top: 33px;
  margin-left: 74px;
  background: #ECE8DF;
  background-image: url("../src/assets/Trolley.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 7px 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Difficult to provide solution without knowing how you are writing it. Trying to give a generalized suggestion here -

1. Use style={{zIndex: 2}} for navigation bar and style={{zIndex: 1}} for header component
2. Alternatively, you can use CSS and in that case replace zIndex with z-index
3. You may want to use position attribute (relative/absolute) for zIndex to work (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: I just needed to add position: absolute to the nav-logo